# How to select values in a CHOICES field?

Tags: infopath, caml

I'm using a CAML query to update a SharePoint 2010 List from InfoPath. My CAML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch OnError="Continue">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="Update">
        <Field Name="ID"></Field>
        <Field Name="Title"></Field>
        <Field Type="Choice" BaseType="Text" Name="Process">
            <CHOICES>
                <CHOICE>Choice 1</CHOICE>
                <CHOICE>Choice 2</CHOICE>
                <CHOICE>Choice 3</CHOICE>
            </CHOICES>
        </Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

For the Title field I just set the value to whatever text I want but I don't know how to set which choices are selected for the Process field. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Fired up Wireshark and looked at the XML coming back from SharePoint and saw how to do this. Basically you just set the Field's value to a string with each choice separated by ;# for example if Choices 1 and 3 were selected:

```
<Field Type="Choice" BaseType="Text" Name="Process">;#Choice 1;#Choice 3;#</Field>
```